# setting info.plist properties for GPS location based app

Tags: iphone, ipad, gps, location, info.plist

I am doing one GPS location based app. It is a kind of GPS alarm app. For that what are the properties should I include under 'Required device cababilities' in info.plist file? Should we include both 'gps' and 'location-services'? I am having one iPad... If I include 'gps', my app is not installing on that. If I include both, what are devices my app could be installed? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Standard location services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager) are available in all versions of iOS 2.0 or higher. Since all iOS (iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad) device have Wi-Fi radio, your application can be installed on those device.

For example: since iPod touch only uses Wi-Fi for Location Services if a Wi-Fi network is available.  This means if your application is running with Wi-Fi off, it just won't receive any data.  And on iOS 4.0 or higher, the user can disable location services for your application.

If you want gps accuracy, will only install on [iPhone and iPad Wi-Fi + 3G only](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1975), i.e . devices with cellular radio.  It's not available on original iPhone or iPad Wi-Fi.